# jQuery Center Div toggle in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Click the button to center div, click again to left align. This works in all browsers except IE6. IE6 doesn't support `margin:0 auto;` How can i work around this. div width is dynamic and not always 200px.

**Check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hZ23J/1/**

```
<button id="center">Left Align</button>
<div></div>

$('#center').toggle(function() {
    $('div').css('margin', '0');
    $(this).text('Center Align')
}, function() {
    $('div').css('margin', '0 auto');
    $(this).text('Left Align')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE6 use

```
body{
text-align:center;
}
```

And your jQuery code will look like

```
$('#center').toggle(function() {
    $('div').css('margin', '0');
    $('body').css('text-align', 'left');
    $(this).text('Center Align')
}, function() {
    $('div').css('margin', '0 auto');
    $('body').css('text-align', 'center');
    $(this).text('Left Align')
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/jNWYP/1/

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me in IE6...

```
$('#center').click(function () {
    $('div').toggleClass('center');
});
```

class...

```
.center { margin: 0px auto; }
```

It's also good practice to keep your JS and CSS separate when possible.

Here is my doctype...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: @Pinkie here is the exact code I'm using in my IE6 test: http://jsfiddle.net/sS975/

Comment: @Pinkie I'm not using quirks mode. Try using the doctype I posted.